# How to track progress of a long job in Amazon EMR with pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

My code comprises of one long job:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("PythonPi")\
    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

from time import sleep
import os
def f(_):
    sleep(1.0)
    print("executor running") # <= I can find it in the log, but only after the job ended
    with open(os.path.expanduser("~/output.txt"), "w") as f: # <= can not find this file on master node
      f.write("executor running") 
    return 1

from operator import add
output = sc.parallelize(range(1, 1000), 400).map(f).reduce(add)
print(output)
spark.stop()
```

How can I track progress of this job when running on Amazon EMR ?

I tried to save to file, but I can not find the file on the master node. As far as I understand - it is saved on the executor node and it is impossible to access it with ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a metric `Tasks (for all stages): Succeded/Total` on Spark History server:

[image]